# Comment created on articles page not saving to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Not sure why comments created on _comment_form.html.erb is not being rendered on articles/:id

I'm referencing this youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUUThhcGtzc

Comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_article

  def create
    @comment = @article.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:content, :article_id, :user_id))
    @comment.user = current_user
    @comment.save
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      redirect_to @article
    end
  end

  private

    def set_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    end

end
```

Articles controller:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
    before_action :set_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show
    @comments = Comment.where(article_id: @article).order("created_at DESC")
  end

  private

    def set_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

_comment.html.erb (from articles/show.html.erb)

```
    <%= render 'comments/comment_form' %>

    <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
       <%= comment.content %>
    <% end %>
```

_comment_form.html.erb

```
<% if user_signed_in?  %>
  <%= form_for ([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :content %>
      <%= f.text_area :content, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>

    <%= f.submit 'Post Comment', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end
```

Comment: Because the comment is not saved. For a quick fix, replace `@comment.save` with `@comment.save!` and you'll see why it can't be saved. (_I'm betting that some presence validations are not met_)

Comment: Also don't take `article_id` from params. Do this: `@article.comments.create(params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :user_id))` (also have a hidden field for `user_id` in the comment form)

Comment: Thank you! Yeah.. it was cos there were validations not met.

Answer (score 0):

Some considerations I would like to do:

```
@comment.save
if @comment.save
```

When you do that, you're saving twice. Calling `@comment.save` on if condition already saves the article and return `true` or `false` if it was successful. Also, replace `.save` for `.save!`, so it will raise an exception in case it doesn't save, so you can check the reason on rails server log.

Also, think it's unnecessary to do this:

```
@comments = Comment.where(article_id: @article).order("created_at DESC")
```

Since you already set the `@article`, you can access `@article.comments`, once you put `has_many :comments` on article model.

You can also check on rails console if the Article was created correctly. Create a new one, and get it like `article = Article.last`, then you can check `article.comments`.

Hope this helps!